# overheating in laptop sony vaio VPCCB

Tags: overheating

i own a sony vaio laptop VPCCB. i have ubuntu 12.04 installed side-by-side with windows 7.
while using ubuntu the laptop gets heated a lot compared to windows and the fan keeps spinning continuosly. i have jupiter installed please help....

Comment: probably you don't have all the drivers installed

Comment: how should i do that, please help

Comment: i am using ubuntu alongside windows 7 but it does not cause any problem in windows please help me with the driver installation... help!!!!!!!

Comment: As of Ubuntu 14.04, you no longer need to follow this method. The kernel v3.13 included has support for automatic graphics switching, so your external ATI graphic card will be in DynOFF state by default (OFF till it is really necessary. Enjoy!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey even I have the same laptop. The problem here is that our laptop contains 2 graphic cards **1.AMD 6630**  **2.Intel HD 3000**
Somehow, by default Ubuntu keeps both of them running, even if only one is used, that leads to overheating.
The solution is to turn off one graphic card.Here I show how to disable ATI card, and just use the Intel HD graphics.
Enter this command in the terminal to check the graphic card status

```
cat /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch
```

you will get o/p like

```
 0:DIS: :Pwr:0000:01:00.0
 1:IGD:+:Pwr:0000:00:02.0
```

here DIS=AMD card, IGD=Intel card.
Pwr on both the lines means that both are powered.To turn the DIS off, enter

```
sudo echo OFF > /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch
```

check the status again. you should get Off on the 0:DIS line.This means only the low-power intel card is running.Use you laptop for an hour or two, and feel the difference.
If it is indeed running cooler, to make the changes persist even after reboot, edit the rc.local file.

```
sudo gedit /etc/rc.local
```

and add the following line above exit 0

```
echo OFF > /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch
```

Comment: nice.. but wont it affect the applications i can't run without the amd graphics card??

Comment: u r awesome!!! thanx

Comment: dude intel HD3000 is already very powerful for all productive work in ubuntu...all 3d transitions, effects work smoothly. so it wont be a problem

Answer (score 0):

My Laptop is: Sony Vaio VPCCB B3M1E

In my case, I just did this:

```
sudo gedit /etc/rc.local
```

Added the following line above `exit 0`

> echo OFF > /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch

And it solved the problem.